# Matlab Javabuilder using GWT

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, matlab, matlab-deployment

Anyone know how to integrate the Matlab compiler runtime with Google Web Toolkit?

Basically, I have GWT client-server app where the server side does some big computation using Java components compiled using the MATLAB Builder JA.  Then server side sends the result back to the client (typical stuff).

I get the GWT app to compile fine but I can not access any of the .dylib files in the Matlab compiler runtime directories once running.

Typical error:

Caused by:

> java.security.AccessControlException:
>   access denied (java.io.FilePermission
>   /Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v713/runtime/maci64/libmwmclmcrrt.7.13.dylib
>   read)

I know that it's killing my access b/cuz of sandbox issues.  But, I have to access these dylib files somehow.  What is the best/secure way to to integrate these libraries with GWT?

Additional info:

- using Mac OSX 10.6.5
- Eclipse JavaEE Helios + GWT 2.1 and app-engine plugin

Any help would be awesome.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not necessary to integrate with GWT. Because GWT is pure client side. You must access MATLAB or any libraries from servlet. So you must integrate your matlab libraries with java servlets. Try access them from simple java application and use in servlets in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine and Matlab are not good options to use together. Therefore I recommend you not to use Google App Engine. You can use , any other server side technology such as servlet for matlab computation..

Comment: Should/could I deploy the GWT app on Tomcat instead of GAE.  Then I could allow access to these dylib files via the Tomcat policy file?

Comment: yep, you should use tomcat instead of gae.. your servlet that is deployed to tomcat can access any file on the computer that tomcat run...